# Why is the wordpress fatal error not being displayed?

Tags: php, wordpress, error-handling

Our site was migrated due to issues on our server providers end. It caused many errors and I fixed most of them. Now, for some pages, it just says there is an error. It display notices and a depreciated warning but I know this will not cause the entire page to stop working. Why is the fatal error not being displayed?

This is what I have tried.

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', 'error.log' );
    ini_set('display_errors','on');
    ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL );
    define('WP_DEBUG', true);
    define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Normally it would show a fatal error. I don't know why it isn't showing me the important error.

Please help!

Comment: Looks right. Could be your server settings not allowing php ini settings override. Check php.ini and make sure you have something like `error_reporting=E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT` and `display_errors=On`. Or try to turn it on from your .htaccess with `php_flag display_startup_errors on` and `php_flag display_errors on`

Answer (score 1):

First ensure that there is no place in your code where you set **error_reporting to 0**
e.g.

```
error_reporting(0);
```

as this will totally hide all error warnings and notices.

In php script, this three line of code will just turn it on

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

You should see the same messages in the PHP **error log**.

Other things that you will need to check

**1.) PHP.INI Files or your Apache configurations**

You can move to your **php.ini** files and ensure that the following parameters below are commented out and set on.

By commented out, I mean removing a semicolon**(;)** at back of it

Eg.

**uncomented**  = ;display_errors=On

**commented** = display_errors=On // semicolon removed

```
display_errors=On
display_startup_errors=On
track_errors = On
html_errors=On
```

shutdown and restart apache for it to take effect.

**2.) .HTACCESS Files**

You can also check **.htaccess** files to see if any of these warning parameter flags are set to **0** which means off and set them to **1** which means On.

**Remember to turn off all these error warnings in production.**

Comment: There were 2 lines where display_errors were defined in PHP.ini, thanks!